# How to make customize info on share dialog

Tags: jquery

I add this meta in `<head></head>` but the share dialog can't not find it ??

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TEST PILOT: test"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="[YOUR URL]"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="TEST PILOT: description"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rockomole.com/2012/blog/2012/may/03.jpg"/>
```

Share button code:

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't believe a different window can access the HTML of the original page.

Answer (score 0):

Are the og meta tags on a publicly accessible page?
Unless you use the Facebook Javascript API (which you are not) the page needs to be publicly accessible from the facebook servers so it may crawl the page and read the tags.